# Rails role-based auth with roles stored in database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Does exists gem, that implements following things:

- User can has many roles
- Each role has group of permissions
- Each permission just boolean
- Roles and permissions stored in database (most important)

For example, I want for something like this:

```
if current_user.can?(:read_all, :list_of_orders)
...
end
```

And `can?` method should search, does any of roles allows it.

Comment: I'm know about cancan, but it roles defined in file, and I can't add some new roles while app is running.

Comment: After some musings I'm desire usage devise + cancan and serialized roles array stored in model field. Just because runtime management of role permissions not required :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Zippie question, I suggest you going with CanCan but you can also use along with it for authentication. See the following links which you will find useful [Rails 3 Authentication and Authorization with Devise and CanCan (Part 1)](http://starqle.com/articles/rails-3-authentication-and-authorization-with-devise-and-cancan-part-1/) & [Rails 3 Authentication and Authorization with Devise and CanCan (Part 2)](http://starqle.com/articles/rails-3-authentication-and-authorization-with-devise-and-cancan-part-2/).

You could potentially have something like this in your `ability.rb`

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
   # raise user.role?(:administrator).inspect
    if user.role? :administrator

      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User

    elsif user.role? :employee
      can :read, :all

    end

  end
end
```

So that in your views you can do something like

You can also use the `can?` in your controller to create your necessary filters as well.

Answer (score 1):

See devise for user authentication and you can define your roles there:

```
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise
```

or even better, combine it easily with cancan:

```
https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try cancan gem, It is powerful

https://github.com/ryanb/cancan

for example:

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

you can Defining Abilities in a `ability.rb`

```
can :manage, Article  # user can perform any action on the article
can :read, :all       # user can read any object
can :manage, :all     # user can perform any action on any object
```

Comment: Yes, cancan is great solution, but I need dynamicaly (in runtime) manage roles.